# Amazon EC2: How to restore ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I accidentally overwrote the entries in .ssh/authorized_keys.
Now I am no longer able to connect to my EC2 instance using my .pem file.
I tried to generate a new .pem file, hoping that process will add entries to .ssh/authorized_keys, but it didn't. I tried to read the documentation, but it is slightly confusing for me.
Someone who can give a simplified explanation/instructions on this is much appreciated.

Unfortunately, there are no active ssh sessions.. :(

Comment: Is there any active ssh session to your instance?

Comment: no active ssh sessions..  :(

Comment: You are out of luck. There is a laborious process of detaching root volume, attaching to another instance, fix your file, then reattaching it etc., it is still possible to salvage your instance but needs some work.

Comment: I do have an active ssh session,What to do in that case? @helloV

Comment: @RBz use the active session to fix the issue and test it.

Answer (score 7):

If the instance is EBS-based, you can do the following:

1. Get a *correct* copy of the `authorized_keys` file ready. Get it off another one of your instances, or reconstruct it from whole cloth, or grab it off a snapshot, or use a new pem file, or whatever.
2. Stop the instance you can't reach (*do not terminate it*). This step is unavoidable. If you can't stop the instance because it's running something important, you're SOL.
3. Detach the root volume from the stopped instance. It should be something like `/dev/sda1`. Be sure to give it a name so you can find it in your volume list.
4. Attach it to a different instance at another mount point, say `/dev/sdp`.
5. Mount the volume into a tmpdir on that instance. Say with `mkdir /tmp/myrootvol && mount /dev/xvdp /tmp/myrootvol`. Note the device name will vary based on your version of Linux (if you're using Linux at all). Much older versions will use different nomenclature.
6. At this point, you've got a filesystem, a root volume, mounted at `/tmp/myrootvol`. Fix the `authorized_keys` file, then unmount the device, and detach the volume.
7. Reattach the volume to the original instance at `/dev/sda1` or whatever device name it was originally attached at.
8. Start that instance back up.

There you go. You'll have an accessible EC2 instance. But wow that was a pain wasn't it?

Comment: I stuck at step 4, not sure how to ssh inside because its still giving Permission Denied (publickey)

Comment: on step 5, I had to mount /dev/xvdp and the partition number so /dev/xvdp1...cause i could not mount the boot partition

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Upload your new public key (`Network & Security` > `Import key pair`)
3. Connect to your instance using web-based client `EC2 Instance Connect` (`AWS console home` > `Instances` > `Your instance` > `Connect to instance` > `EC2 Instance Connect`). No key is required for this!
4. Go to your home directory. `/home/ubuntu`, for example.
5. Run `mkdir -m 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh`
6. Copy-paste your public key using `nano /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`
7. Run `mkdir -m 600 .ssh/authorized_keys`

Now you should be able to connect using your public ip address using `ssh -i path_to_your_private_key ubuntu@public-ip`.

More details: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors